# Display items with matching id

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to create a filter that only shows items with a matching id, at the moment it only works the other way round. What has to be changed in the function hideIds?

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kdqdj9en/1/)

NG

```
var app = angular.module('m', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.subtree = [{
    id: 1,
    name: susan
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: peter
}, {
    id: 3,
    name: marc
}, {
    id: 4,
    name: julia
}, {
    id: 5,
    name: sylvia
}, {
    id: 6,
    name: martin
 }];


  var arr = [1,2,6];


$scope.hideIds = function (ids) {
    return function (item) {
        return arr.indexOf(item.id) === -1;
     }
   };
});
```

template

Comment: Please paste relevant markup as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing `=== -1` you can do `!== -1`.  `.indexOf` will return `-1` if the array does not contain the element.  This means that `[1,2,6].indexOf(5)` returns `-1`, but `[1,2,6].indexOf(1)` returns `0`.